# Image blurring on a UIButton - but not when UIImageView

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a bit of an odd problem with an image I'm using in a UIButton backgroundImage property. As you can see from the picture, the foreground image (in an UIImageView) is much clearer, whereas the background one, is blurred and not as good looking - this is a image on a UIButton.  [image: UIButton in background and UIImageView in front]

Thoughts? Things to try? Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm doing this all in IB.

Comment: What is the size of the image related to the button and image view? I can only see a slight difference along the top border, is that the area you're concerned about? The screenshot would be more helpful if the elements weren't overlapping each other so you could see them against the same background.

Comment: The UIImageView and UIButton are the same size as the png they're referencing, 522 × 164 on a retina display.

Comment: The same size? Usually you would have, say, a 100x100 button, a 100x100 image called image.png and a 200x200 image called image@2x.png. Perhaps image view and button have different scaling optimisations, the button could be scaling your image up and down, resulting in the lower quality?

Comment: I had another look at the pngs, and they don't seem to be exactly double... this could and probably is the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retina and not retina file sizes were not exactly double. Keep your designers informed guys...